# Does OSX support (importing) OpenVPN profiles?

Tags: network, vpn

Is there some way to import the settings of an OpenVPN client into the built-in VPN client in Mountain Lion? Or am I comparing apples to oranges?

Comment: It does not but please assure that you request this feature at http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html -- it matters if you want the feature!!

Comment: you would probably be much better off using radar.apple.com

Answer (score 18):

## No.

As of Sept 2012 (and Mountain Lion), macOS does not support OpenVPN in the built-in "Network Manager".

Out-of-the-box macOS only supports:

- **L2TP over IPSec**
- **PPTP [(not recommended)](https://www.cloudcracker.com/blog/2012/07/29/cracking-ms-chap-v2/)**
- **Cisco IPSec**

However, you can use the following third-party OpenVPN clients in macOS:

- [Shimo](http://www.chungwasoft.com/shimo/)
- [Viscosity](http://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/)
- [Tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net/) (open source, free)
- [pritunl client](https://client.pritunl.com/) (open source, free)

I can confirm that both Shimo and Viscosity support the import of `.ovpn`profiles.

Comment: Tunnelblick does too. I've distributed `.ovpn` profiles in the past to users.

Comment: Update: El Capitan supports [IKEv2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange) as well.

Comment: @kojiro so does that mean we can use `.ovpn` to connect now?

Comment: I do not know, but would love to hear about it.

Comment: Hello from 2022! Nothing changed. Still using Tunnelblick...

Comment: Anyone know why not?